# I am trying to create registration form with django forms.But when i enter data it returns ValueError at /register?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create form using django forms.I created registration form when i enter data and click on submit it returns ValueError at /register and if i enter wrong data for example invalid email its not showing corresponding error?

```
  def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Register(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data['Email']
            User_name=form.cleaned_data['Username']
            Password=form.cleaned_data['Password']
            Confirm_Password=form.cleaned_data['Confirm_Password']
            User.objects.create_user(username=User_name,
                                            password=Password,email=email)
            return redirect("register")
    else:
        form = Register()
        return render(request,'register.html',{'form': form})

  <!------register.html--->
  {% extends 'layout.html' %}
  {% block content %}
  <div class="box">
    <h2>
        <center>Register</center>
    </h2><br>
    <form action='register' method='POST'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div>
            <label>Email:</label>
            {{ form.Email }}
            {{ form.Email.errors }}
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Username:</label>
            {{ form.Username }}
            {{ form.Username.errors }}

        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Password:</label>
            {{ form.Password }}

        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Confirm Password:</label>
            {{ form.Confirm_Password }}
            {{ form.Confirm_Password.errors }}
        </div>
        <input type="Submit" id="lg"/><br>
        <center><a href="login" >Already have an account.Login here.</a> 
                                                  </center>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div>
    {% for message in messages%}
        <h1>{{message}}</h1>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
  {% endblock %}

  forms.py
  from django import forms
  from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  from django.core.validators import validate_email

  class Register(forms.Form):
    Email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs= 
                                                {"class":"inputvalues"}))
    Username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs= 
                                                {"class":"inputvalues"}))
    Password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs= 
                                               ({"class":"inputvalues"})))
    Confirm_Password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs= 
                                             ({"class":"inputvalues"})))

    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = ['email','username','password']

    def clean_Email(self):
        try:
            validate_email(self.cleaned_data['Email'])
        except:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Email is not in correct format!")
        return self.cleaned_data['Email']
    def clean_Username(self):
        try:
            User.objects.get(username = self.cleaned_data['Username'])
        except:
            return self.cleaned_data['Username']
        raise forms.ValidationError("Username already exist!")
    def clean_Confirm_Password(self):
        pas=self.cleaned_data['Password']
        cpas = self.cleaned_data['Confirm_Password']
        if pas != cpas:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Password and Confirm Password are 
                                                           not matching!")
        else:
            if len(pas) < 8:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Password should have atleast 
                                                             8 character")
            if pas.isdigit():
                raise forms.ValidationError("Password should not all 
                                                                 numeric")
```

Showing Error Message : ValueError at /register
The view blog.views.register didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Comment: change `return redirect("register")` and render a complete template instead

Comment: I tried not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In views.py

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Register(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            ........
            return redirect("register")
        else:
             return render(request,'register.html',{'form': form})

    else:
        form = Register()
    return render(request,'register.html',{'form': form})
```

> In register.html display errors like this:

```
{% if form.errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            {{ form.errors }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: is class="alert alert-danger" a bootstrap class?